# DevExpress LookUp repository item binded to dictionary set members

Tags: c#, dictionary, devexpress

I have created a dictionary with an int key and a string value. I managed to set the dictionary as the datasource of my LookUp field. The lookup field is a repository item in a devexpress GridControl. The dictionary values are shown in my LookUp but I want to set the display and value member (and the caption) and don't know how to do this. Below you can see the current situation.

[image]

The dictionary code:

```
       Dictionary<int, string> IncIncControls = new Dictionary<int,string>()
       {
       { 1, "IncIncidentId"},
       { 2, "IncIncidentType"},
       { 3, "IncIncidentPriority"}
       };
```

And the code to set the LookUp source

```
pageFieldLookUp.DataSource = (from d in IncIncControls
                                      orderby d.Value
                                      select new
                                       {
                                           d.Key,
                                           d.Value
                                       }).ToList();
```

How to modify the code to set lookup source in a way that I can set the display member/value member and caption. Or is there another (better) way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`RepositoryItemLookUpEditBase.DisplayMember`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditBase_DisplayMembertopic) and [`RepositoryItemLookUpEditBase.ValueMember`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditBase_ValueMembertopic) properties for set display and value members, and use [`RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.Columns`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEdit_Columnstopic) property to set captions:

```
pageFieldLookUp.DataSource = (from d in IncIncControls
                                      orderby d.Value
                                      select new
                                       {
                                           d.Key,
                                           d.Value
                                       }).ToList();
pageFieldLookUp.ValueMember = "Key";
pageFieldLookUp.DisplayMember = "Value";

pageFieldLookUp.PopulateColumns();

pageFieldLookUp.Columns[0].Caption = "Key caption";
pageFieldLookUp.Columns[1].Caption = "Value caption";
```

Comment: @nempoBu4 is it possible to hand event changed in vb for this RespositoryItemLookUpEdit

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Sorry, I don't understand what are you talking about.